# if statement doesnt work when included with two variables

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a simple login system with the help of javascript. Unfortunately, the if statement doesn't work as I've intended it to. The page doesn't redirect when the enter key is pressed.

```js
var objPeople = [
 {studentid: "input1"},
 {studentid: "input2"}
]

var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    for(i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++){
      if (myInput == objPeople[i].myInput && event.keyCode === 13){
        window.location.href = "www.google.com"; 
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
        <title>aaa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `if` statement works correctly. My guess is `myInput == objPeople[i].myInput` isn't comparing what you think it is.

Comment: `objPeople` dose not have `myInput `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myInput`  is undefined for your event, you should get the value by adding following line in your `eventListener`.

```
 let myInput= document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

Change your code like following.

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  let myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  for (i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++) {
    if (myInput == objPeople[i].studentid && event.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log(objPeople[i].studentid);
      window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit:** Sample

```js
var objPeople = [{
    studentid: "input1"
  },
  {
    studentid: "input2"
  }
]

var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  let myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  for (i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++) {
    if (myInput == objPeople[i].studentid && event.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log(objPeople[i].studentid);
      window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
  <title>aaa</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="myInput">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry, i am new to javascript. Apparently the code doesn't work. I want the page to redirect to google after input1 or input2 is typed into myInput then enter key pressed. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @80yeast, i have added working sample, you can have a look