# I want to make a login page using javascript. Something is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a simple login system with the help of JavaScript. I want the page to redirect to google after John or Neil is typed into the textbox after enter is pressed. Help?

```js
var objPeople = [
 {studentid: "John"},
 {studentid: "Neil"}
]

var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    for(i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++){
      if (myInput == objPeople[i].myInput && event.keyCode === 13){
        window.location.href = "www.google.com"; 
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
        <title>aaa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `objPeople[i].myInput` but you have no properties named `myInput`... also, to check the value of an input, you need to check the `.value` property

Comment: Also, you should move the loading of your script to the end of the body tag since it won't identify the input elements as it is loaded before them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if statement doesnt work when included with two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849290/if-statement-doesnt-work-when-included-with-two-variables)

Comment: How does it come your question is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849482/i-want-to-make-a-login-page-using-javascript-something-is-wrong-with-my-code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the value of input and use the name of the variable in which the element is stored the the id name. And to access the object property you have to use the property name not the id of the input.

```
input.value == objPeople[i].studentid
```

```js
var objPeople = [
 {studentid: "John"},
 {studentid: "Neil"}
]

var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    for(i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++){
      if (input.value == objPeople[i].studentid && event.keyCode === 13){
        window.location.href = "http:\\www.google.com"; 
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
        <title>aaa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
    </body>
</html>
```